# yii2 REST api for file upload

Tags: php, rest, file-upload, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Im trying to upload a file image/file type from mobile app and store that image in the backend. Im using Yii2 framework API to do this. And im using postman to check the API. Im running the below in my action.

```
/*Uploading documents*/ 
      public function actionUploading_doc() {  

         $uploads = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('upfile');

         print_r($uploads);exit;

          if (empty($uploads)){
              return "Must upload at least 1 file in upfile form-data POST";
          } 

          foreach ($uploads as $file){
              $filename = time() . $image->name;
              $path = "uploads/" . $filename;
              $file->saveAs($path);  
          }
       }
```

When i run this as POST method from postman.. and print the value of $uploads im getting empty value. It mean its not coming to controller. 
Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is what i did without the UploadFile class

```
  /*Uploading documents*/ 
      public function actionUploading() {  

         $uploads = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('upfile');

         \yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = false;
          $filename = $uploads->name;
          $path = "http://localhost/projects/YiiRestful/api/web/uploads/".$filename;
          $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
           // make sure that you have /web/upload directory (writeable) 
           // for this to work
           $path = "uploads/".$filename;

           $fp = fopen($path, "w");

           while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
              fwrite($fp, $data);

           /* Close the streams */
           fclose($fp);
           fclose($putdata);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this... (not tested)

```
public function actionUploadingDoc() {  // good practice to use camel case for methods
    $uploads = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances('upfile');
    if (empty($uploads)){
        return false;
        // handle error reporting somewhere else
    } 
    $path = 'uploads/'; // set your path
    foreach ($uploads as $upload){
        $filename = $path . time() .'_'. $upload->name ;
        $upload->saveAs($filename);  
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 string to uplod. define function inside controller like this

```
public function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
    $path="your/real/path/";
    // open the output file for writing
    $ifp = fopen( $path.$output_file, 'wb' ); 

    // split the string on commas
    // $data[ 0 ] == "data:image/png;base64"
    // $data[ 1 ] == <actual base64 string>
    $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );
    if(count($data)>1) {
        $dataText=$data[ 1 ];
    } else {
        $dataText=$base64_string;
    }

    // we could add validation here with ensuring count( $data ) > 1
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $dataText ) );

    // clean up the file resource
    fclose( $ifp ); 

    return $output_file; 
}
```

And use inside action as

```
public function actionUpload(){

    $imgName=md5(uniqid()).'.jpg';
    $this->base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $imgName);
}
```